# Android - Change value in strings.xml

Tags: android

So inside strings.xml I have a string called change_bg  and I'd like to change it's value according to click events.

I know that in order to get the value you use

```
changeBG=getString(R.string.change_bg);
```

But I don't know how to SET the value of 
`R.string.change_bg`

Please let me know how.

Thanks in advance!
Dvir

Answer (score 11):

You can't change resource files during runtime. Strings are hard-coded in the `string.xml` file and hence can't be changed during runtime. Instead of trying to edit your `strings.xml` file, just use `SharedPreferences` to store the user's preferences if that's what you're trying.

Answer (score 5):

You basically must understand that strings we normally hardcode, now we do it in string.xml

the strings that are variable in nature must not be defined in string.xml

You can set its default value in `onCreate()` of your MainActivity i.e Launcher Activity.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change the values of `strings.xml` at run time. I had the same doubt, when I started with android development. Just remember that `strings.xml` can only be set before running the application manually and after that, you cannot modify it. You will understand the reason for that in the due course.