# How to change text in string-array in Values/Strings?

Tags: android, arraylist

> I have this Array list in my project i wonder if there is anyway to
>   change the text in every item to another string programmatically ? i'm including the
>   picture of that array list

[Array list that i have wanna change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpKD0.png)

Comment: You mean put instead of Pole another name?

Comment: Please edit the question appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's not possible to change anything the String resources. Please see the link below for a duplicate question:
[Android - Change value in strings.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632428/android-change-value-in-strings-xml)

Also please see the documentation
[here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

Comment: I knew it late today, and i know the sharedpreference methode but thanks anyway