# Add string.xml resource run time on Android

Tags: android, xml, resources, translation

I need to translate my app through external files which are added manually in an external folder (such as Download, so not embedded in the application). Example: my app runs only in English, if someone wants to add another language, he creates its own string-xx.xml file which is loaded by my app and then such language can be selected (then the app translates itself). Is it possible to do this kind of work? Is there any workaround if not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android - Change value in strings.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632428/android-change-value-in-strings-xml)

Comment: Maybe, it would be better to use https://localazy.com/android where users can translate the app for others comfortly and it supports over the air delivery of updated translations and new languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading string.xml at runtime is not supported in Android, if you want to add runtime translations, you will have to create your own translation service and your app will send requests to it.

You could mimic the same interface Android has to get string values and the method will call your service internally.